# How to take 3 random letters from first name , 2 from last name and phone number and 1 symbol from the given string 'specialChar'

Tags: java, string, random, passwords, generator

```
public class testingstring {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    
       String specialChar = "!@#$%^&*()" ;
    
       System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
       String firstName = userInput.next() ;
    
       System.out.println("Enter your last name: ") ;
       String lastName = userInput.next() ;
    
       System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ") ;
       String phoneNum = userInput.next() ;

   }
}
```

The program should randomly generate 8 characters long password as follows:

1. 3 random letters from the first name
2. 2 random letters from the last name
3. 2 random digits from the mobile phone number
4. 1 random character from the variable 'specialChar'

Answer (score 0):

1/loop n times
int index = (new Random()).nextInt(specialChar.length());
then put specialChar.charAt(index) in  a result array for each string.

Comment: can you give me an example code for firstName please

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into smaller pieces.  Say the first name is "Patrick".  How do you go about picking three random letters from the string "Patrick"?  Write a small piece of code to do that and test it.  Then add it to your program in the right place.

Use a similar logic to pick from the last name and the string of special characters.

Comment: No.  We are not a code writing service.  You write your own code, post it here and we will help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeneratePass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] Arr = new String[4];
Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] N = new int[4];
char[] Pass = new char[8];

System.out.println("What is your first name?");
Arr[0] = S.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your last name?");
Arr[1] = S.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your mobile phone?");
Arr[2] = S.nextLine();
Arr[3] = "!@#$%^&*()";

for (int pos = 0; pos < 4; pos++) {
    N[pos] = Arr[pos].length() - 1;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
            Pass[count] = Arr[0].charAt((int) Math.round(Math.random()*N[0]));
            break;
        case 1:for (int count = 3; count < 5; count++)
            Pass[count] = Arr[1].charAt((int) Math.round(Math.random()*N[1]));
            break;
        case 2:for (int count = 5; count < 7; count++)
            Pass[count] = Arr[2].charAt((int) Math.round(Math.random()*N[2]));
            break;
        case 3:for (int count = 7; count < 8; count++)
            Pass[count] = Arr[3].charAt((int) Math.round(Math.random()*N[3]));
            break;
    }}
System.out.print("Your new password: ");
for (int pos = 0; pos < 8; pos++) {
    System.out.print(Pass[pos]);
}}}
```